# 25th Oct being Surya grahanam & amavashya...one needs to do both separately or together & correct timing

Tags: rituals, sri-vaishnava, eclipse, amavasya

Namaskaram to All!

Today (25th Oct'22) being a surya grahanam + Amavasya... Does one need to do both Tharpanam separately as per time indicated by seniors or together as one instance with specific instructions. Elders, Kindly guide as i could only do pithru tharpanam in the morning.

Comment: Found this explanation & thought should share, as found convincing... (1st 4 mins) https://youtu.be/WHCMZmY6adE                                                                                                                        Anymore clarifications would be welcome 